# Is it possible to schedule an svn update?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, subversive

I use eclipse galileo with [subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) plugin or Tortoise SVN to do an update.

It is possible to schedule an auto-update (eg. every night)? 
If yes, is it possible to configure it to just update the non-conflicting files?

Comment: Primo, this is a superuser.com question, Secundo, it's a question about the OS, not Subversion/Eclipse.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I use this command via a scheduled task - this assumes you have Silksvn installed (but any svn client will do this)

```
"C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\svn" update --accept postpone d:\SourceCode >> c:\svn.log
```

It will only update files that aren't conflicting also, so no worry about that.

OR even, do it from TortoiseSVN using this command

```
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:d:\sourcecode /closeonend:1
```

closeonend can be one of these

```
/closeonend:0 don't close the dialog automatically 

/closeonend:1 auto close if no errors 

/closeonend:2 auto close if no errors and conflicts 

/closeonend:3 auto close if no errors, conflicts and merges 

/closeonend:4 auto close if no errors, conflicts and merges for local operations
```

Comment: Anyone have it where the /closeonend param doesn't actually close the dialog? We set it to :1, but there are connection errors about once a day that cause errors, so it ends up hanging all the svn updates to our QA server.

Comment: `/closeonend:0` keeps the dialog open, as the answer says.

Answer (score 3):

Just schedule a task to run a batch file every night. The batch file just calls an svn update using a Subversion command line client. Simple enough, right?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the popup lingering when the connection dropped, so I just installed a command line version of svn and checked the returned ERRORLEVEL using a Windows batch script

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Task Scheduler or CRONw